# How to put account info into facebook login form and click submit button in web browser control?

Tags: c#, facebook, autocomplete

as the title ! Who can help me this problem ?
thanks!

i tried code:

```
HtmlDocument put = this.webBrowser1.Document;
put.GetElementById("input").SetAttribute("value", "abc");
```

i can see element username but password unknow element???

but not work for me! :(

Comment: Where have you put this code? Are you sure the page has fully loaded at this point?

Comment: yes! web browser loaded 100%, this my above code

Comment: why would anyone want to fill in the account info AND auto-click the submit button? a submit button is there to be blicked by the user.

Comment: luschn: That is the task of the app , not the user ! I want my app to do it when it auto loaded username and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this would be to send an automated post request to the server with the parameters that you have specified. You will get HTML in return that you can parse then.

Use `WebClient` for this.

Here is an example:

```
string URI = "http://www.server.com/login";
string myParameters = "username=value1&password=value2";

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
}
```

Comment: sir: i don't understand "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", what's this?

Comment: It's simply a content type that you need for this request. The focus should be on *myParameters*. Bear in mind that there are APIs that you could use for e.g. Facebook, which is better practise than my example. My example is specific to your question - but not good practise in this case.